# Android handle orientation change w/o rotating screen

Tags: android, rotation, screen, orientation

How to handle screen orientation without rotating screen?

I have override `onConfigurationChanged` in my activity and try to comment out call `super.onConfigurationChanged` and my application Force Closes. Next thing I've tried was to set orientation attribute in newConfig parameter of this method to `newConfig.orientation = Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;` before call `super.onConfigurationChanged`. But still my screen has rotated.

My last implementation would be to handle sensor (gyroscope) movement. But is there any other way to do this?

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your manifest  file, add this to your activity which you don't want to rotate:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

This will prevent it from ever rotating, including if the phone has a slide out keyboard.

I hope this helps.

Comment: OK. But when orientation occurs I want to do something. How to?

Comment: Try this example. I don't have one myself but if I remember correctly it was almost exactly like this:

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/08/orientationeventlistener-detect.html

Comment: Allright!! That's exactly what I have been looking for! Thx man!

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to restrict your activities to only one kind of orientation, then add the following to each of the activites in your manifest file:

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

Comment: This locks device's orientation. OK. But now I want to handle screen orientation and also have it in always portrait mode.

Comment: This locks it to potrait mode